# Perform bound javascript event handlers asychrounously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I bound two `onchange` events to my select box.

```
var function = f1(e) {
    // Codes to run
}

var function = f2(e) {
    // Codes to run
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var elmt = $("#select-box");

    elmt.unbind("change");
    elmt.bind("change", f1);
    elmt.bind("change", f2);
});
```

I understand that upon `onchange` trigger my `#select-box` element, it will perform both `f1` and `f2` sychronously. What I want to achieve is that upon `onchange`, it will ***first*** perform `f1`, since it is bound first. Then after, `f2`- one after another, ***not sychronous***.

Please do also understand that my scenario requires me, thus I ***cannot***, put `f2` inside `f1`, or the other way around just to achieve this effect.

Are there any way to do this? Also, this is a simplified version, the real codes binds three function to a single event, at the least. Thanks!

## EDIT

There are `AJAX` call within `f1` and `f2`. And I cannot put it into another dummy function let say:

```
function f3(e) { f1(e); f2(e); }
```

Comment: Can you put f1 and f2 in another function f3?
Like: function f3(e){
f1(e);
f2(e);
}

Comment: JS is single threaded. The functions won't run simultaneously.

Comment: Does `f1` start any async operations like AJAX? If not, they won't run concurrently, as @Oriol said.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to tell. Both have AJAX calls.

Comment: Use [`.then()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything.

JS is single threaded. That means that, while some code is running, other codes must wait before being run. So the function won't run simultaneously.

And according to [`bind` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), the order will be the desired one:

> If there are multiple handlers registered, they will always execute in
>   the order in which they were bound.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to tell. Both have `AJAX` calls.

Comment: @GideonApolloBardelas That does not matter, the functions won't run simultaneously even if you use AJAX. If you mean you want to run the second function after finishing the first AJAX request, call it in the callback of the request, instead of making it an event listener.

Comment: If that's the case, maybe I should look somewhere else... Thanks for the help.